# Constructor global variable error javascript Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ctx' of undefined at update

Tags: javascript, canvas, constructor

I am trying to use the `this.ctx`. ... in update to make the constructor clean and ready to be put in a different file but i had an error with that that if you would like to help me with great but that is not necessary.

Now the error is

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ctx' of undefined
>     at update
> ```

Here is the code of the file:

```js
    // global variables
    var canvas, ctx, net, Canvas, ai;

    // init stuff
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = 100;
    canvas.height = 100;


    class Ai {
      constructor(x, y, width, height, ctx) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.ctx = ctx;
      }

      drawAi() {
        this.ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
      }

      update() {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(ai.update);
        this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 100, 100);

        ai.drawAi();
      }
    }

    ai = new Ai(10, 10, 15, 15, ctx);

    ai.drawAi();
    ai.update();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Also the html tags are there.

Comment: No but thanks for trying to help

Comment: [Should work](https://jsfiddle.net/4p7faxLt/).

Comment: @Noahr Yes it does. It's exactly the same question, same problem, same solutions, just different method names